# Why does having a transition for a icon not occur when the button is unhovered?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I wanted to add a effect where an icon showed up and disappeared smoothly when the button is hovered. The effect occurs with no issues when the button is hovered, but unlike other effects, it only works one way.

Note: I used Ionicons but the issue persists with several other icon libraries.

```css
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.buttonicon {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

button:hover .buttonicon {
  transition: 1s;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<button>
  Button Text
  <ion-icon class="buttonicon" name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Because you put the `transition` part on the `:hover` styles. When the element isn't hovered any more, it doesn't have a `transition`. The `transition` should (generally) go on the default state, so in `.buttonicon` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite Simple Rather than adding `Transition Property` on `button:hover .buttonicon` class apply transition on `buttonicon` your final output will be look like this.

```
.buttonicon {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

button:hover .buttonicon {
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your css, you can add

> transition: 1s

to .buttonicon instead of :hover selector. In this way the transition property will be applied to all transitions regarding the button, so you'll have the "smooth" effect.